# Windows Mobile and VS2008, can't connect to device

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I just got myself a new toy, a phone with Windows Mobile 6. I'm trying to write a simple "Hello World" app in VS2008 (C#) and I can't connect to the device. It's connected via ActiveSync (via USB), I can browse the file system, but for some reason when I try to build the app and deploy it to the device, it says "Connect to device failed."

I installed the Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK as well as the .net Compact Framework 3.5 runtime on the device and all that worked fine. I can run the app on the emulator, but for some strange reason I can't connect to the device. I know this isn't alot of info to go on, but I'm at a total loss!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities, but most likely it has everything to do with security.  Carriers have the option to [lock a device](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2007/05/14/what-do-you-mean-by-locked.aspx) to prevent you from installing "unauthorized" applications.  There is also the granularity of security.  Many devices can run apps, but only if they are signed.  Some devices allow you to change this setting, or they at least will tell you that an unsigned app is attempting to run and ask you if it's OK.  Using the [Device Security Powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7e92628c-d587-47e0-908b-09fee6ea517a&displaylang=en) might allow you to provision the device to allow you to deploy.  Read more on provisioning [here](http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/faqs/provisioning/provisioning.htm) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894922.aspx).

You might need to sign the app with either a [development certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158503.aspx) or a real one - especially if you plan to deploy the app.

Comment: Wow. Great info, let me look into that. Pain in the a$$!! But thanks for the info!