# VS2008 remotely connect to Win Mobile 6.1 Device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

So I've been given to a Windows Mobile 6.1 Classic Device to work with for a project, but I was given a network adapter for it and not a USB cable. So I have to build and test across the network.

So how do I get Visual Studio to connect to the device across the network? I have read the following articles to no avail:

- ["How to: Connect to Windows CE Device Without ActiveSync"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

and also looked at:

- [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389238/windows-mobile-and-vs2008-cant-connect-to-device)

But neither have helped me, I am not sure what to try next to try and get Visual Studio 08  to connect to this device remotely

I can ping the device, but I can't connect to the device. I know the device is connected to the network because while it is in the cradle it can browse the internet.

What am I missing to get this to work? If it can work in the first place...

**Edit**: To make it clear, the issue I currently have is not to do with Debugging. It has to do with Visual merely *connecting* to the device.

**Edit 2**: If it helps I don't have a Windows Mobile 6.1 Classic Device in my list of Devices to connect to. I have;

- Windows CE Device
- Windows Mobile 6 Professional Device
- Windows Mobile 6 Standard Device

Comment: I didn't know VS2008 could connect to a mobile device through a network connection. If your device manufacturer makes an SDK that allows this, you could go that route. Out of the box? I don't think VS2008 can do it.

Comment: Hi jp2code. Remote SmartDevice debugging in VS2008 was always there.

Comment: One more NOTE: you will never love the MS naming strategy of device OS and Platforms or VS versions: "Windows Mobile 6.1 Classic" can be handled as "Windows Mobile 6 Standard Device". "Windows Mobile 6.5.3" is now also "Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3". Dont wonder, just choose a 6.x SDK without Professional (or just do not use Phone features). You can even choose a WM5 device and Platforms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### **How to connect Visual Studio 2008 to SmartDevice using TCP/IP without ActiveSync/WMDC**

### Remote Files

You need the following files of your VS2008 Windows Mobile SDK installation:

```
ClientShutdown.exe
cmaccept.EXE
ConManClient2.exe
eDbgTL.dll
TcpConnectionA.dll
```

change registry key HLKM\System\CoreConOverrideSecurity=DWORD:1 on device

The files you need are located at (depends on Windows CE version on device):

Windows CE 4.2, Windows CE .NET, Windows Mobile 2003, PocketPC 2003:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\target\wce400\armv4i

For Visual Studio 2008 and a Windows CE 5 based SDK you can use ftp \hjgode.de\temp\rdb2008.exe tool (used in following example) or the original [rdb2008.exe](http://www.turboirc.com/ppc/s5.htm) source.

**Check the IP of the device**

[image: IP address of device]

**Start rdb2008.exe on the device**

[image: rdb2008 on device]

**Press [Prepare] in rdb2008 will extract files and set reg entry

[image: rdb prepared]

### Prepare VS2008

Ensure you use a matching Windows Mobile SDK. You may use Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional SDK also on a Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic device. Or you use Window Mobile 6 SDK with a Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic device. Just use a appropriate SDK for the device.

**Setup VS2008 remote device IP and Port**

Select Tools-Options-Device Tools-Devices

[image]
Select a appropriate Platform here (show devices for platform)! But as said, it is sufficient to match the basic OS (Windows CE 5).

After Selecting the right Platform select a device (no Emulator) and then click [Save As]
[image]
Enter RemoteDebug as new name.

Now select the new RemoteDebug saved entry in Devices...
[image]

... and click [Properties]:
[image]

Now enter a directory for file deployment (here: "\Program Files").
Ensure Transport is "TCP Connect Transport" and click [Properties]
[image]

Ensure you use the fixed port 5655 and then enter the IP address of the remote device!

Now close all these option dialogs using the [OK] buttons.

### Test the connection

In VS2008 ensure the Platform and the device is active:
[image]

Now click Tools in VS2008 menu and then on "Connect to device"
[image]

Again check the Plaform and Device, do not yet click [Connect]:
[image]

Now on device: Click [Start] in rdb2008:
[image]

You see rdb2008 says listening Port 5655!

Now click [Connect] in VS2008:
[image]

Hopefully you got the above dialog and go on with another test. Click [Close].

In VS2008 select Debug-Attach to process:
[image]

Select Transport=SmartDevice and click Califier:[Browse] and again select the used platform and device "RemoteDebug":
[image]

If sucessfull, you will see a list of running processes on the device.

Comment: Perfect! PPC RDB Solved the connection issue. I upvoted both questions for your effort. Thanks for sticking with me on this one ^.^

Answer (score 1):

you can use remote deploy and debugging without using an ActiveSync/WMDC connection.

**Manual Setup**

First you have to copy some files onto your device:

```
ConmanClient2.exe
CMAccept.exe
eDbgTL.dll
TcpConnectionA.dll
```

The files can be found here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\target\wce400\armv4i.
Change wce400 to wce500 for your Windows Mobile 6.x devices.

To allow remote debug connection on device, you have to start *ConnmanClient2.exe* and then *CMAccept.exe* on the device.

**Visual Studio setup**

Open menu Tools-Options and navigate to Device Tools-Devices. Select the platform for your windows mobile device and then a Devices entry. Click on [Copy] to create a new entry for your device and name it, for example, RemoteDebug. Select your new RemoteDebug entry and click [Properties]. Normally all devices use ActiveSync settings. We will switch to a TCP/IP setup. In RemoteDebug's Properties dialog select Transport=TCP Connect Transport. Click [Configure] In Configure TCP/IP Transport Dialog select option "Use specific IP address" and enter the IP address of the device.Then close the VS dialogs by clicking the [OK] buttons.

Now, you can start deployment and debugging from visual studio using the fixed IP address instead of an ActiveSync one.

**Notes**

Be aware that you have to start deployment and/or debugging within some time frame after you started ConnManClient2 and CMAccept on the device.

**Automatic Device side Setup**

I can provide an automatic install of the device side files later the day.

**Download/Upload files on device**

You can copy or download the device side remote debugger files either using a memory card or by providing them (single or as cab) on a web server in your network, that you can browse with the device and download.

[Sources](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205617/Debugging-Managed-Applications-in-Windows-CE-Devic), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That is just a reformatted version of the MSDN Article I linked. This doesn't answer my question as to. "Why can't I connect to the device"

Comment: Possibly you have to set: HLKM\System\CoreConOverrideSecurity = 1 DWORD

Comment: Is that on the device or on the PC?

Comment: The key has to be set on device. Can you provide model name of device?

Comment: Motorola MC55. The Problem is I am unable to connect to the device. But I can ping the device and the device can ping my machine

Comment: OK, you are running Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic (no phone additions). Let me dig...