# Debug WM 6.5 application without ActiveSync connection

Tags: connection, windows-mobile, activesync

Is there a way to debug my application (running on `Windows Mobile 6.5`, deployed on `Visual Studio 2005`) without `ActiveSync`?
I want to go through some connection problems and with the `ActiveSync`-connection always enabled, I can't really test the WLAN and/or GPRS-module with my application.
I tried disabling the USB-connection in `ActiveSync`, but then Visual Studio cannot connect to my device and I am not able to debug my project. (It does disable the connection on my device though).
Am i missing some settings I can change on my device and/or ActiveSync?

Comment: duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195717/vs2008-remotely-connect-to-win-mobile-6-1-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to do this when you are trying to debug over `WWAN/GPRS`.
But it works if you connect your device to your office network/the network you are also developing with, see [Debugging Visual Studio applications with no ActiveSync support](http://community.psion.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/750.debugging-visual-studio-applications-with-no-activesync-support.aspx).
Note: this may not work with all devices running WM6.5, in my case this was a Psion EP10 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This one

http://www.turboirc.com/ppc/s5.htm

works fine for me with VS 2008 and WM 6.5

Take a look at
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2005/04/28/413304.aspx
as well.